# Is there a R function to apply in filter option in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have the below code. I need to put a main filter in mainpanel so that i can select the categories that in turn should change the numbers (summary)

```
# faithful is the dataset
# Iris is the dataset
 iris$New <- ifelse(iris$Sepal.Width>2.5,"greater than 2.5","Not Greater 
 than 2.5")
library(shiny)

sample1 <- 1:3

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        "x",
        "Operations",
        choices = c("summary","stem","typeof","mode","birth"), 
        multiple = TRUE,
        selectize = TRUE
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h6("Here it is"),
      verbatimTextOutput("message")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$message <- renderPrint({
    if(input$x == "summary"){
      summary(iris$Petal.Width)
    } else if (input$x == "stem"){
      print(stem(faithful$eruptions))
    } else if (input$x == "typeof"){
      typeof(sample1)
    } else if (input$x == "mode"){
      mode(sample1)
    } 
  }) 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Can I have a main filter of "Species" from Iris dataset. When I select "setosa",the summary should change accordingly

Comment: I think you might need to use `switch` instead of multiple if-elses, not sure though.

Answer (score 1):

If we need to change the `summary` based on the values of 'Species', use `renderUI` with `uiOutput`

```
sample1 <- 1:3
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(selectInput("x","Operations",choices = 
                               c("summary","stem","typeof","mode","birth"),
    multiple=FALSE,selectize = TRUE)),
    mainPanel(h6("Here it is"),
              verbatimTextOutput("message"),
              uiOutput("Species")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  r1 <- reactive({

    if(input$x == "summary")
    {
      summary(iris$Petal.Width[iris$Species == input$Species])
    } else if (input$x == "stem")
    {
      print(stem(faithful$eruptions))
    } else if (input$x == "typeof")
    {
      typeof(sample1)
    } else if (input$x == "mode")
    {
      mode(sample1)
    } 
  }) 

output$message <- renderPrint({r1()})

  output$Species <- renderUI({

    selectInput("Species", "species", 
      choices = as.character(unique(iris$Species)), multiple = FALSE)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Perfect got it. May I know what is summary(iris$Petal.Width[iris$Species == input$Species]) is doing here. If I need to apply "sapply" function here. What example : sapply(iris,function(x) length(unique(x))). I need to see that are the distinct counts under species category

Comment: @JanaP  It is selecting the elements of 'Petal.Width', that corresponds to the UI entry for 'Species'.  So, if you select 'versicolor', the 'Petal.Width' would be that filtered values corresponding to the elements where 'Species' is 'versicolor'.    If you need the distiinct counts, you can do `library(dplyr); iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise_all(n_distinct)`  If it is for each entry that corresponds to UI species, then `iris %>% filter(Species == input$Species) %>% select(-Species) %>% summarise_all(n_distinct)`

Comment: perfect thanks. Also i have edited my question , lets say, I have added another column to Iris data set.Now I need multiple filter along with "Species" to get the summary output

Comment: @JanaP  I answered your initial question.  Please consider to add questions as a new question